Custom param decorator is only for controller in nestjs?
Is the custom param decorator in nestjs is only for the controller?
I am trying to apply it on the param of the function of a class, but when m calling that function it says expected 1 argument, which means decorator is not applied,
here is the sample code
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common'

// Custom parameter decorator
const MyParamDecorator = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
    return 'DefaultParameterValue'
})

class MyClass {
  myFunction(@MyParamDecorator() param?: string) {
    console.log('Parameter value:', param)
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass()
instance.myFunction() ``` 


The custom parameter decorators are to instruct the framework how to handle parameters from where the framework controls the code calls to where the dev controls the code calls. Because of this, they are not valid inside of services, and will only work in controllers, resolvers, and gateways, where the framework hands off the execution of the code from internally managed functions to dev written ones. From there, devs are in charge of passing the data/variables accordingly
